# Property 'nextUrl' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'. in Nextjs and Typescript

Tags: typescript, http, next.js

I am using [Nextjs API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes), and trying to get the request parameters:

```js
export const GET = async (req: IncomingMessage) => {
    const matchString: String = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("data")
}
```

I believe the type of `req` is `IncomingMessage`(please correct me if I am wrong); however, `req.nextUrl` is getting `Property 'nextUrl' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'.`, what's wrong, and how should I debug it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The type for `req` should be `NextRequest`. Your code should be something like:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
    const matchString = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("data")
}
```

Comment: how can I know the type of `req` is `NextRequest`, I tried to search the typescript api route/request in nextjs, couldn't find the answer `NextRequest` at all.

Comment: @TungTung you can check the official docs reference https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#request-optional